# Labtop or Laptop?

Tags: word-usage

Is it a "labtop" or a "laptop?"

A desktop is called a desktop because it is put on top of the desk when used, so "labtop" must be the correct term because it is portable and can be carried to the lab.

Is this correct? If not, why not?

Comment: The portabile computer, which people often place on **top** of their **lap**, has  been called "LAPTOP" for at least twenty years if not longer. I have never heard nor read anyone calling that machine "labtop". Did you look up either terms in an online dictionary? What did you find?

Comment: When you take a *laptop* to the lab, you place it on a desk to use it.  So, by your logic, it would be called a *desktop*.  You don't place it on top of the lab.

Comment: Many Arabs call it a labtop because there is no **p** in arabic. I often see signs in Egypt that say **no barking**... and they are not talking about dogs.

Comment: @Chenmunka so funny

Comment: @LMS I can give you lessons in Deutsch Spraches if you want ;D

Comment: @JavaLatte That reminds me of the story about a medical student who, after being shown how to use a hypodermic syringe, was told by his instructor to go and practice on a bear.

Comment: Mostly unrelated, but I remember in Sabrina the Teenage Witch one of the aunts had a lab which folded up to look like a laptop case. That's the only instance I can think of of somebody intentionally using the word "labtop" and it was definitely just a little joke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's laptop because the idea was that instead of placing it on your desk top, you place it on top of your lap. A laptop is a portable computer, one that is light enough and compact enough to be used with it resting on one's lap (the flat surface formed by your thighs when seated -- credit to LMS for definition). Previous portable computers were bulky devices which were made rugged for transport and easy to setup.

The name has nothing to do with where it might be used (e.g. a lab).

In practice, laptops are commonly used resting on a flat surface except for where that is impractical/impossible (like waiting at an airport).

Your uncertainty is understandable since /b/ and /p/ are closely-related sounds. Depending on your native language, they may be hard for you to distinguish.

In particular, if you speak without emphasizing the syllable break, *labtop* will sound a lot like *laptop* because the /b/ will partially devoice due to the /t/ following

Comment: For anyone unaware, the "lap" is the flat area made by the thighs when you sit down ([dictionary definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lap)).

Comment: @eques LMS's comment ought to be included in your answer, it seems to me, given that comments are ephemeral, and that this point is critical to the question.